# Bluetooth does not work in dual booting computer (windows and Ubuntu)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, bluetooth, windows-10

I have a computer with two hard drives, the main one is Windows 10, and the other disk has Ubuntu 20.04. I can boot and move between both disks but there is a problem; When I move from Ubuntu to Windows the Bluetooth does not work, it never connects to any of my devices, then I must uninstall and install the Bluetooth driver on Windows. So far I have not found how to fix the problem or what is causing it. 
**I would appreciate any advise to fix the problem permanently (not uninstall and install the driver each time that I move between disks)**

Comment: If the problem is on the Windows side you are asking in the wrong place. You can ask about Windows issues on SuperUser.  Otherwise, if the problem is on Ubuntu, please edit your question and include more details and context. What have you found so far in your research trying to find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Does the problem persist if you do a complete, proper, poweroff from Ubuntu, wait-10-seconds, and then poweron into Windows?

Comment: Yes, the problem persists after I power off Ubuntu, even when I do it and turn off the computer on Windows more than 10 minutes later Bluetooth does not work. @user535733

Comment: I was reading that I needed to match the id keys for Bluetooth on both OS. I am really not using Bluetooth on Ubuntu, then I did not match them because it seemed risky. For my specific problem, I have not found an answer for my problem @Nmath